# Using matrix.postRotate() to rotate a bitmap and add it to a canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am trying to rotate a bitmap and add it to a canvas. The code seems straightforward, however the image is not being rotated. I can't use canvas.rotate() since I am layering images and do not want the first image to be rotated. I have verified that the rotation degree is correct with tattoo.getRotation(), and I have also tried this with a hard coded degree but that doesn't work either.

```
public static Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {

    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
    Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix();
    matrix1.setScale(imageView.getScaleX(), imageView.getScaleY());
    matrix1.setTranslate(imageView.getX(), imageView.getY());
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, matrix1, null);

    Matrix matrix2 = new Matrix();
    matrix2.setTranslate(tattoo.getX(), tattoo.getY());
    matrix2.postRotate(tattoo.getRotation());
    matrix2.setScale(tattoo.getScaleX(), tattoo.getScaleY());
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, matrix2, null);

    return bmOverlay;

}
```

Comment: `setScale` resets the whole `Matrix`: you are loosing both translation and rotation

Comment: Wow! Who knew? Thanks a lot pskink.

Comment: nobody knew, google guys like to surprise... ;-)